# (Node) Running many if statements at the same time always returns undefined after 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

Edit: I can't believe I forgot what I was asking! I always get typeError Undefined for whatever the sixth if statement is testing. When I swap around the fifth/sixth statements the if(!data.body.main) comes out as undefined which it doesn't when in the fifth position however I can't figure out why.

So I'm trying to test POST data from express/bodyparser for its contents and then fill default information to be used by the rest of my program if the fields aren't set in the post data.

To do this I'm running many if statements in a list like so:

```
function setChannelOptions(data, channelSettings){
    console.log('Setting channel options');
    var channelOptions = {
        channelName: data.body.name,
        mainNumber: data.body.main,
        backupNumber: data.body.backup,
        music: data.body.music,
        spoofNumber: data.body.spoof,
        price: data.body.price,
        customerId: data.body.customerid,
        allowOutbound: data.body.allowoutbound,
        welcomeMessage: data.body.welcomemessage,
        accountCode: data.body.accountCode
    }

    if(!data.body.accountCode){
        channelOptions.accountCode = findChannelID(data.body.name, function (err, data) {
            if(err) throw err;
            return data.channelid;
        });
    }
    if(!data.body.allowoutbound){
        channelOptions.allowOutbound = 0;
    }
    if(!data.body.welcomemessage){
        channelOptions.welcomeMessage = 'sometext';
    }
    if(!data.body.price){
        channelOptions.price = '-1';
    }
    if(!data.body.backup){
        var data = 'NG';
        channelOptions.backupNumber = assignNumber(data, function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        return data.number;
        })
    }
    if(!data.body.main){
        var data = 'VU';
        channelOptions.mainNumber = assignNumber(data, function(err, data){
            if (err) throw err;
            return data.number;
        })
    }
    channelSettings(null, channelOptions);
```

I feel like it might be caused by the callback at the end returning before all of the if statements are complete but without nesting each of these if's in callback functions I wouldn't know how to stop that.

Thanks for having a look, I'm a bit new to node and JS in general.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Please be specific.

Comment: you should use `data.body.hasOwnProperty('accountCode')` to know if a property is present

Comment: That `findChannelID()` part won't work, I bet; that looks like an asynchronous API.

Comment: are `findChannelID` and/or `assignNumber` asynchronous?

Comment: I've added an edit to make the question clearer.

Also the functions within each of the statements work fine.

Comment: You redefine your `data` like in `if(!data.body.backup){   var data = 'NG';` and after that you test `if(!data.body.main){`, when `data` can be string, something is not OK in this place.

Comment: @pttsky apparently I can't even read. Thanks for spotting that. I've now changed `var data = 'NG';` to `var optionBackup = 'NG'` and surprise surprise it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using other name for your variables. You use `data` identifier as incoming parameter of your `setChannelOptions` function, and then redefine it with `var` keyword. Variables defined with `var` are functionally, not block-scoped. Refactor your code to something like:

```
if(!data.body.backup){
    var code = 'NG';
    channelOptions.backupNumber = assignNumber(code, function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    return data.number;
    })
}
if(!data.body.main){
    var code = 'VU';
    channelOptions.mainNumber = assignNumber(code, function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        return data.number;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you redefined your `data` arg. You should probably copy data at the top of your function and use that copy instead.

```
if(!data.body.backup){
    var data = 'NG'; // <----- redefinition
    channelOptions.backupNumber = assignNumber(data, function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    return data.number;
    })
}
if(!data.body.main){ // data === 'NG'
    var data = 'VU';
    channelOptions.mainNumber = assignNumber(data, function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        return data.number;
    })
}
```

Comment: This is correct, @pttsky also got this, thanks for fixing my dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Use promise library like bluebird.

require a promise library

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'); // install it using nom
```

Declare a array of promises as

```
var promises = [];



 if(!data.body.accountCode){
   promises.push(
    findChannelID(data.body.name).then(function (data){
        channelOptions.accountCode = data.channelid;
    })
   );
}

//.....rest all other checks

 Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
    channelSettings(null, channelOptions);
 });
```

you will need to convert your callback function (like findChannelID) to return a Promise. which is very simple as

```
function findChannelID(name){
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     //.. do you math here 
     // finally return value as
     // resolve(the calculated value);
     resolve({data:{name: 'something'}})
  });
}
```